# delete from table view when using json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I've created an application that pulls data from my external database using json and populates a table view. It all works fine but I now want to be able to delete one of the data items in the table view by sliding a delete button across. This is my code for my secondview controller that gives me an error message. In the header file I also set an `NSMutableArray` called `json`.

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
return self;
}
-(void) getData:(NSData *) data{

NSError *error;

json = [ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

[self.tableView reloadData];

}

-(void) start{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kGETUrl];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

[self getData:data];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(start) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];


[self start];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [json count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell ==nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"message"];



return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
   [json removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
  //  [tableView reloadData];
} 
}
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
[self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

I'm aware that I'd need to code it to delete from the actual DB using php, etc. But for now I just want it to delete from the table view. This is the error message I get : 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
json = [ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

gives you an immutable array (`NSArray`) but your code uses `json` like it is an `NSMutableArray`.

You have two choices:

1) Change the line to:

```
json = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

or

2) Change the line to:

```
json = [ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Comment: thank you i do not have enough points to upvote you, but as soon as I do i will come back and give the upvote you deserve

Answer (score 0):

your JSON object is immutable i.e. It can not be modified.

You could pass the object into a NSMutableDictionary constructor and then use that to build your tableview / delete rows etc

`NSMutableDictionary *mutableJSON = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:JSON];`